# Как вызвать функцию с параметром в другой функции в kotlin

Tags: kotlin

У меня есть функция, которая возвращает некоторое значение. В параметре функции я передаю то же значение:

```
 fun getValue (value:String):String {
        var message = value
        value = "Hello"
        return message
    }
```

Как я могу вызвать функцию `getValue` в другой функции? Например:

```
fun getResult (){
var a = getValue (what here?)
}
```

Comment: А чем не устраивает var a = getValue("Hello")? Или Вам нужно передать функцию в параметре?

Comment: @ Crush, Мне нужно ,что бы в результате было: `a =message` . т е мне нужно получить значение, которое возвращает функция `getValue`

Comment: ну по логике ведь нужно что-то передать в getValue, либо можно засетить дефолтные значения но тогда результат будет, так же не очень понятно где используется переменная value после присвоения ей значения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В комментариях вам верно ответили. Вызов getValue с параметром вернет то, что нужно. Т.е. в примере `var a = getValue("Hello")` переменная 'a' будет равна значению, которое вернет функция getValue.